# ASP.NET MVC Data Annotations DateTime Default Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, data-annotations

In my **ViewModel** I have the following attribute:

```csharp
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyyy")]
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

In my **View** I have the following:

```html
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
</div>
```

Before submitting the form the default value for `DOB` is `1/01/0001`, how do I stop this value from being auto-populated, I simply want an empty field when people visit this form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you will have to use the nullable DateTime? type.  DateTime cannot be null thus it will always have a value.

Answer (score 6):

Try making the DOB DateTime nullable like @Mayo states:

```
public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is of type struct. So, by default DateTime cannot be null. It has default value equal to '01/01/0001'. 
Solution to your problem is to use the nullable DateTime? type.
If you want it to default to some value like '01/01/2014', then you can assign value like:
DOB = new DateTime(2014, 01, 01);