# How to initialize the date picker in Edit view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[image]

I have a model as follows:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Genre { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 100)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [StringLength(5)]
        public string Rating { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The date picker is enabled by default but when Edit view is in view, the date field does not automatically reflect the previous value. How to initialize the date picker when the Edit view comes up?

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Please, show view syntax. As example look at [Setting initial value for DataType.DateTime in model][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790096/setting-initial-value-for-datatype-datetime-in-model

Answer (score 0):

Create an folder in shared named EditorTemplates and put a file name DateTime.cshtml.
Then you add following code to the file.

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.Date.ToShortDateString()))
```

Comment: Added the folder EditorTemplates like Views/Shared/EditorTemplates? And the file in that folder?

Comment: I have got same problem many times and solved it liked that, yes its works. So I dont understand why its not working for you.

Comment: Could you submit your complete visual studio project/solution for this?

Comment: Sure I can sumbit a sample project. Where do u want me to upload it?

Comment: Please submit to me via `the(dot)counterterrorist(at)gmail(dot)com`. Thank you in advance.