# Controlling the default value and format of Form elements Generated using view Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am generating Form elements using a Model Class as below

```
Public Class BookAppointment
    Property DoctorNin As Integer
    Property PatientNin As Integer
    Property BookingDate As Date

    Property Doctors As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
End Class
```

When I pass this View Model to the view page, some of the values are already there as default value but they are invalid.

Like for `PatientNin` I use

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.PatientNin)%>
```

When the form gets rendered, it get a `0` as a default value, which is unwanted. How to control such default values?

In the above case, same happens with `BookingDate` and in the textbox I get `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` Which is out of format and unwanted default value?

How to solve problem like this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351969/asp-net-mvc-data-annotations-datetime-default-value

Answer (score 0):

The default value of an `integer` type will be `zero`. So if you are not assigning any values to it. It will bring zero as the value.

If you do not want the default zero value, you can switch your property to `Nullable` type.

Comment: I only want no `0` in the form field. I am ok with them at other place.

Comment: Then Probably you can use string type which is nullable in your ViewModel instead of int

Comment: But... how will it validate the data as number then

Answer (score 0):

Changes default value to 100 if its not greater than 0:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) If(x.PatientNin > 0, x.PatientNin, 100))%>
```

Comment: I got an error `Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.`